# Destroying records based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to destroy a record in my Liabilities table. Within this table there is a person and page fields. I am attempting to find a Liability record where the id is 5 and the page is show.

```
person = person.find_by_id(5)
page =  Liability.where(page: 'show')
if person == 5
 page.destroy
end
```

This does not delete the record. Why?

Comment: Liability.where(page: 'show') returns an ActiveRecord association, not a model.  Need  Liability.where(page: 'show').first

Comment: Do you mean `destroy_all`?

Comment: destroy_all also will not delete the records

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not checking outputs step by step. One or more of your statements can produce error or nil output. Below are corrected statements to do that. Morover, @Lee Drum is also right, you would either use destroy_all or select one page/liability. I assume, you wanna delete only one liability. Please note that what you're referring by `page` variable is actually a Liability object having an attribute `page`.

```
person = Person.find params[:person_id]
liability =  Liability.find_by_page params[:page_name]
if person && person.id == 5 && liability.present?
  liability.destroy!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with:

```
liability = Liability.where(page:'show').where(person_id: 5)
liability.destroy_all
```

This correctly found any record in the Liability table containing the page 'Show' and with a person_id of 5. It also deleted these records.

Answer (score -1):

`Liability.where(page: 'show')` return an array association not an `object`
you should use `page.destroy_all` in this case

Comment: I've just tried destroy_all. When I check the database no records are deleted.

Comment: Correct syntax is ```Liability.destroy_all(page: 'show')```

Comment: @SolitaryCoder because your condition never matches. `person` is an object from Database, not an `integer`. the condition is always falsely